# mosh + osx + /bin/false error

Tags: macos, ssh, broken-pipe, mosh

I have successfully installed mosh at server and client side both. I am trying to ssh using mosh from osx but it is throwing following error:

```
/bin/false: No such file or directory
write: Broken pipe
/usr/local/bin/mosh: Did not find remote IP address (is SSH ProxyCommand disabled?).
```

I am not sure if it has anything to do with mosh, or it is general error. Please help me in setting up mosh.

Comment: Ask on https://apple.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

This error

```
/bin/false: No such file or directory
```

most likely means the user account that you are trying to login to is disabled. You need to log in as another user, and change the shell to a valid executable

```
$ chsh -s /bin/bash [username]
```